# Activemq authentication and authorization with data base

Tags: activemq-classic, message-queue

I Work with Activemq And needed to use the existing mysql or mongo database for user authentication and authorization to allow clients to send or receive message on the topic. But I dont know how do this work

Comment: have a look here http://activemq.apache.org/security.html

Comment: I see this page but not find anythings about  authentication and authorization with data base

Comment: @vuhar i have already gone through that page and found no DB based authentication and also do you know how can I add a new user dynamically to auth files using java ?